# When using Dependency Injection with StructureMap how do I chooose among multiple constructors?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, dependency-injection, structuremap, ioc-container

I'm trying to get structuremap to build Fluent Nhibernate's `SessionSource` object for some of my intregration tests.  The only problem is that Fluent's concrete implementation of `ISessionSource` (`SessionSource`) has 3 constructors:

```
    public SessionSource(PersistenceModel model) 
    {
        Initialize(new Configuration().Configure(), model);
    }

    public SessionSource(IDictionary<string, string> properties, PersistenceModel model)
    {
        Initialize(new Configuration().AddProperties(properties), model);
    }

    public SessionSource(FluentConfiguration config)
    {
        configuration = config.Configuration;

        sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
        dialect = Dialect.GetDialect(configuration.Properties);
    }
```

I've tried configuring my `ObjectFactory` supplying an argument for the first constructor but it seems like it wants to try the second one.

How do I configure my `ObjectFactory` so that I can choose the first constructor or perhaps even another one if I decide to use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your registry you can do it like this:

```
SelectConstructor<SessionSource>(()=> new SessionSource((FluentConfiguration)null));
For<SessionSource>().Use<SessionSource>();
```